# Vue.js Spread Operator instead of Vue.set / Vue.delete

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuex

I would like to use the spread operator to add/remove object properties while maintaining [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

In a Vuex mutation, the following works:

```
Vue.set(state.sportTypes.sports, sportName, sportProperties)
```

However I would like to use the spread operator and return new object. How would I achieve the following?

```
state.sportTypes.sports = {...state.sportTypes.sports, {sportName: sportProperties}}
```

Comment: Why would you like to use spread operator to do that? It's ugly and counterperformant since you will recreate a full reactive object from scratch. Maybe you can restart from your needs instead of imposing yourself a linestyle of code

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the brackets of `{sportName: sportProperties}`

This will work:

```
state.sportTypes.sports = { ...state.sportTypes.sports, sportName: 'football' }
```

But I'd recommend you to declare all the possible fields, instead of add new attributes dynamically, then you don't need to use `Vue.set` nor the spread operator.

Comment: how do you declare all possible fields when you have an unknown distribution of incoming data?

Comment: It's technically possible, you can iterate on your incoming data keys, and assign them with Vue.set. But it looks very not elegant. Are you really sure it's needed to mix incoming data into existing one? What is the source of this need?